# Setting up Creative Senz3D Camera with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera, realsense

I'm trying to use the gesture tracking features of the Creative Senz3D camera with OpenCV 3 in Python 2.7 (right now I'm using Anaconda, but I'm willing to change that if need be.)

As of right now, I can get images from the camera, but the image only has 3 channels - there is no way to access the depth and variables like CV_CAP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_MAP don't work. I haven't found any good resources on how to set up Python OpenCV to use the camera's features and was hoping for a reference or a brief explanation about how to move forward.

Comment: The Creative Senz3D Camera is NOT the Intel RealSense Camera (using the current SDK.  It is the older Perceptual Computing Camera which used a 2013 SDK only.

Comment: did you have any luck in getting 3D working in python?